# python, better algorithm than reading file twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I want to start typing my first python program ever! and want some help with (an idea)-please don't type any code.
I want to read a file which contains two types of lines the first look like this:

```
(starts with company)company company_name company_id  
(starts with employee)employee employee_name employee_company
```

My job is to read that file and for every employee to save his name and the name the company he works with.
I though about reading the file twice, first to fill employees names and for each one the company id then to read the file again and replace company_id with the name of the company.
But, this doesn't sound as an efficient algorithm, do you have any better ideas?

please note: the lines are sorted in random way.

Comment: Which field of a company record corresponds to entries in the `employee_company` field?

Comment: This question is more suited to a forum, whereas this is a Q&A site, where specific programming questions get specific answers

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have any reason to load the file twice, which will certainly be the slowest part of your program (though speed won't be an issue).

Your logic can look like this, assuming employee names are unique:

```
for each line in the file
  store employee name -> company id in a dictionary
  store company id -> company name in a dictionary
for each employee name -> company id
  look up company name from company id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the file first, so all of the companies are at the top and all of the employees are at the bottom. Then you can create a dictionary that maps each company id to a company name, and update this dictionary every time you read a company row. Once you reach the first employee row, you've already seen every company, so you can look up the id and replace it right away.

This way, you only have to do a single pass of the data, but there is a performance tradeoff since you have to sort the data first.

That said, for a problem like this, it's almost certainly not worth worrying about whether sorting or doing two passes is more efficient. Even a very inefficient implementation will run much faster than it's taken you to read this!